# ESP32C3 Not Connecting to AWS with MQTT

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, stm32, esp32, at-command

I've been using an Adafruit QT Py ESP32-C3 with an STM32 uC over AT commands. It has been working just fine until I reflashed the ESP32 with new firmware using esp-at. The only difference between this firmware and the one I flashed originally is that I added added the ability to connect with a WPA2 Enterprise network in the menuconfig which doesn't come by default.

Since doing this, the command "AT+MQTTCONN" gives me an error when trying to connect to AWS:

```
ERR CODE:0x010a6021 (AT_MQTT_CA_LENGTH_ERROR)
ERR CODE:0x010a6009 (AT_MQTT_TLS_CONFIG_ERROR)
ERR CODE:0x010a600a (AT_MQTT_PARAM_PREPARE_ERROR)
```

All my certificates from AWS were present when building the firmware and worked the first time I did it. All the commands I run are exactly the same, but I get this error now. Running "AT+MQTTUSERCFG" works fine and I properly configured my SNTP time. I follow all the steps on the tutorial [here](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-at/en/latest/esp32c3/AT_Command_Examples/mqtt-at-examples-for-cloud.html?highlight=aws):
Any help is greatly appreciated.

*I also understand that I could code directly on the ESP chip. I choose to not do so because I have much more experience with STM32 and enjoy coding at a low level with those devices. I understand that this is a bit clunkier than it needs to be but please work with me.*

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

The esp-at tool wasn't properly updating the partition table that says where all the certs are supposed to go. As a result, none of them were being flashed although I put them in the right place.

You can check this by doing `AT+SYSFLASH` and seeing the result. There should be a long list of all the certs. If not, I recommend not using the esp-at tool but instead the official esp firmware straight from the website. It's less customizable but more reliable since there are less moving parts.